# How can we execute a batch file from the Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to execute a BAT file to create folder(s) on the shared drive over the network. Is this possible in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to execute batch file on SharePoint. Mostly for SharePoint online, workflow/Flow is recommended to do such work.

Workflow: [Workflow To Auto Create Folder Structure While Creating New Document Set In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/workflow-to-auto-create-folder-structure-while-creating-new-document-set-in-shar/)

Flow: [Create Folder In SharePoint List Using Microsoft Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-folder-in-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-flow/)